# Strange behaviour when absolute positioning span around an input

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-position

I am trying to create validation error message for my input boxes, but I have encountered a strange behavior and difference between Chrome and other browsers.

I need to set the error label to display next to inputs, and it should be displayed over other elements.
My approach is working fine in FF but not in chrome.

The problem is that in Chrome the error message falls below the input box.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ewuq44xg/3/

Resize the html preview area to see the effects.

```
.editor-group {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.editor-label {
    min-width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.editor-field {
    min-width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.field-validation-error {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    min-width: 20px;
    position: absolute !important;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    outline: 0 none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #FFF4C9;
    border: solid 1px #FFE79E;
    color: #635145;
    margin-right: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 5px 1px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: .85em;
}
<div class="editor-group">
    <div class="editor-label editor-required">
        <label  for="NameOfReceiptNo1">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-error">
            <span class="k-icon k-warning"></span>
            Name is required
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `float: left` to `.editor-field input` and `float: right` to `.field-validation-error`, also you can remove the `display: inline-block` from `.field-validation-error`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewuq44xg/4/)

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `position:absolute` it's better to specify where exatctly should element exist.
in your example I added `right: -116px; top: 0;` CSS to  `.field-validation-error` and `position:relative` to `.editor-group` the first parent of `field-validation-error` so now `field-validation-error` will know to stay in right side of `editor-group`

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iuDClHg0rkA72jezHAKM?p=preview)

```
.editor-field {
 min-width: 150px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 3px 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
}

.field-validation-error {
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 min-width: 20px;
 position: absolute !important;
 text-align: center;
 z-index: 1000;
 outline: 0 none;
 background-position: center center;
 background-color: #FFF4C9;
 border: solid 1px #FFE79E;
 color: #635145;
 margin-right: 6px;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 2px 5px 1px 6px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: .85em;
 right: -116px; top: 0;
 }
```

Comment: I thought it is clear that the error message is variable and changes from an input to another, thus I can't specify exact numbers as you did in `right`.

Comment: so use `left` instead.you know the width of `editor-filed`

Comment: `left` with combination of `white-space:nowrap` looks good, still not as good as FF results.

Comment: And `editor-filed`'s width is not know always, cause it has `min-width`. This solution doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: yes it's not always have same width,but you can handle it with media-queries.  I think this is the only way around only CSS. or you can use jQuery to calculate the width of `editor-filed` every time

Comment: or if you don't NEED to use `position abdolute`, you can remove it and add `float:left` to both `.field-validation-error` and `.editor-field input`, this way the stay beside eachother,

Comment: Thank you, using the float is the solution, but @Rohit Kumar answer works better and as expected.